# c++ write on specific bits in matrix

Tags: c++, fpga, bitmask

I got a quite simple problem today. I have a matrix `float gradient[COLS][ROWS]`. As you probably know the `float` type includes 32 bits. 
In my code I do 4 different checks on another table. For each of them I want to write in `gradient[][]` the results.

What I would like to do is write these results on 8 bits in `gradient[][]`.
So the LSB would contain the result of the first Check, the 8 following bits the results of the second Check, and so on.

As for the reason I want to do this, it is because I'm trying to synthetize this code using HLS and make it run on a Xilinx ZedBoard. There is however not much memory available on the FPGA, so instead of storing the results of my 4 functions into 4 different matrix I woul like to store them in the same matrix using bit operations.

I know I can use masks with an AND operator like `gradient[][]&0xFF`. What I'm not sure however is when and how do I apply this mask ?

As an example here is the code for one of the Checks (sry for the spanish names i didn't write this) :

```
void FullCheck(float brightness_tab[COLS][ROWS]){
    for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++){
        int previous_point = (int)(brightness_tab[0][i]);
        for(int j=1;j<COLS-1;j++){
            float brightness=brightness_tab[i][j];
            int brightnessi=(int)(brightness);
            gradient[i][j]=brightnessi- previous_point;
            if(!(gradient[i][j]>VALOR_PENDIENTE || gradient[i][j]<-VALOR_PENDIENTE)){
                if(!(gradient[i][j] + gradient[i][j-1] >VALOR_PENDIENTE_TRUNCAR || gradient[i][j] + gradient[i][j+1]<-VALOR_PENDIENTE_TRUNCAR)){
                    gradient[i][j]=0;
                }
            }
            if(j<2 || i<2 || COLS-1 ==i){gradient[i][j]=0;}
            previous_point=brightnessi;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers !

Comment: `As you probably know the float type includes 32 bits.` No, we don't know that. The size and layout is not specified by the language. Relying on assumptions about the representation is a sure-fire way to write ill-formed, time-bomb code.

Comment: I still don't understand *why* you want to perform bit operations on `float`? What exactly is the result of this operation supposed to be (and why does it need to be stored inside the `float`)?

Comment: @underscore_d Well I'm not an expert but : `Single-precision floating-point format is a computer number format that occupies 4 bytes (32 bits) in computer memory and represents a wide dynamic range of values by using a floating point.`

Comment: @UnholySheep Well i could use a `int` type too,I don't think this should be a problem

Comment: @ValentinDubois How a mainstream CPU implements floating point numbers `!=` the guarantees that C++ makes about its `float` type. So, at best, you would be writing inherently unportable code, for no apparent reason. But more so, the cast here violates strict aliasing, so compilers can freely transform the invalid code into anything. Given enough time, could you massage some compiler into doing what you want, Standard-be-damned? Maybe. But it's not clear why you want it, and there's probably a better way.

Comment: @ValentinDubois Per the standard the `sizeof(float)` is implementation defined.  We have no idea what size it is.  In fact is is perfectly acceptable to have `float`, `double`, and `long double` to be the same size

Comment: *"I don't think this should be a problem"* - In that case you seem to not even have tried or researched. C++ does not allow bit operations on `float` (or `double`) - and for good reason

Comment: @underscore_d To be simple, I'm trying to synthetize this using HLS to create an IP running on Xilinx ZedBoard. My main problem is the memory available on the FPGA, which is very low. That's why I thought I could optimize this by writing the results of the 4 functions directly using only one matrix.

Comment: @ValentinDubois That does kinda change things. ;-) Then you can _probably_ get away with what you are trying to do, so long as your compiler guarantees (A) the various types' representations and (B) that it is happy to perform such casts in a guaranteed, implementation-defined way, which might require you passing some extra flags to it. It won't make for good C++ code, though - coding it directly in assembly would be better!

Comment: @UnholySheep What I meant is that I can use int instead of floats if necessary. I may not be an expert in programming but I'm not completely ignorant either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deducing from your comments, I'll assume that `gradient` will be declared as an `int` array.

In your sample code, there are 2 cases for writing something to the matrix. In the first case, you want to write some value, such as this line:

```
gradient[i][j] = brightnessi - previous_point;
```

If you want to write some data to a specific byte, the data you want to write should be a 1-byte data itself.

```
gradient[i][j] = 0;          // initialize to all zero bits
int data1 = 0x12;            // 1-byte value
gradient[i][j] |= data1;     // writing to the 1st byte (LSB)
int data2 = 0x34;
gradient[i][j] |= data2 << 8;   // writing to the 2nd byte
int data3 = 0x56;
gradient[i][j] |= data3 << 16;  // writing to the 3rd byte
int data4 = 0x78;
gradient[i][j] |= data4 << 24;  // writing to the 4th byte
```

After executing above code, the value of `gradient[i][j]` will be `0x78563412`.

The second case is clearing what you have written before by writing 0, such as this line:

```
gradient[i][j] = 0;
```

In this case you can do

```
gradient[i][j] &= 0xffffff00;    // clearing the 1st byte (LSB)
gradient[i][j] &= 0xffff00ff;    // clearing the 2nd byte
gradient[i][j] &= 0xff00ffff;    // clearing the 3rd byte
gradient[i][j] &= 0x00ffffff;    // clearing the 4th byte
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! So for example in my first function, if I want to write on the 8 LSB I use the mask with `0xff`. If I want to write on the 3d byte i would use `0xff << 16` ? I thought I would have to make a mask with `0xff0000` ?

Comment: @ValentinDubois I've updated the answer to include an example case. If it is not the thing you are trying to achieve, then please let me know, so I can improve the post. Also, the original answer had some errors for clearing specific byte, and I've fixed it.

Comment: Thank you a lot to you two for your answer. I changed tha array from `float` to `int` based on @underscore_d advice and checked for any changes, but found none that matter. This way I can use the bit per bit operation given by @nglee. I still have to write a bench in Vivado HLS to see if it really works but for now I admit it as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do a struct that has the same memory layout

```
struct Bytes
{
  uint8_t a;
  uint8_t b;
  uint8_t c;
  uint8_t d;
 } ;

Bytes* g = reinterpret_cast<Bytes*>(&gradient[i][j]);
```

That way you can access the individual bytes easily like `g->a`

Comment: Yes, this will probably work, particularly on an embedded compiler, though formally it's still UB. I'd also add that `uint8_t` is not required to be the same type as the smallest addressable byte unit on any system, which is `unsigned char`, though in most cases it's probably a typedef to the same.

Comment: @underscore_d I don't think it is formally UB, the struct has standard-layout so it should work and given the constraints given regarding portability and size of char it would work.

Comment: The Standard only makes allowances for casting between objects that have related types, not arbitrary objects that happen to have the same layout. Anything else including the latter violates casting rules and strict aliasing. Sure, it will _probably_ work on any compiler that doesn't go to lengths to shoot you in the foot, but it is not required to work at all, and it's a sign of brittle code that could start failing at any moment.

Comment: @underscore_d i agree that it is brittle and non-portable, was just trying to solve his specific problem